# Representation theory of groupoids

Tags: groupoids

Is there for a groupoid an representation theorem as Representation theorem of Wagner-Preston for inverse semigroups?

Comment: Which meaning of "groupoid" are you using here?

Comment: Presumably you want to represent as a concrete category of sets with bijection?  Then Yoneda works

Comment: Groupoid is a category where each morphism is invertible.